# Two different string formats for parsing DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have to parse two different kind of formats of DateTime: `dd/MM/yyy` and `dd-MM-yy`.
The string comes from `item.EmploymentDate` and it is usually one of the two formats and I need it to be parsed as `DateTime` objects.

My code so far:

```
var formatStrings = new string[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyy" };
DateTime.TryParseExact(item.EmploymentDate, formatStrings, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime resultDate);
employee.Details.EmploymentDate = resultDate;
```

However, `resultDate` ends up being a default DateTime object `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}` instead of the values from `item.EmploymentDate`. I can confirm that they are not null. The first one is `"30-03-1999"`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should always check the return value of `TryParse(Exact)` to make sure that the parsing actually worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three `yyy` in `"dd-MM-yyy"` instead of `yyyy`, but 30-03-1999 has 4 digits for year

Comment: Nice catch, I totally missed it! Now I have the same problem but with `"1/9/1997"` , why is `dd/MM/yyyy` not catching it? EDIT: changed to `d/M/yyyy` and it worked!

Comment: @crystyxn because it is `TryParse**Exact**`... Try `01/01/1997`. If you want to accept both `01/09/1997` and `1/9/1997` use `d/M/yyyy` (and then correct the other specifier)